# Inclusion of certain libraries causes service not to start C++ (fastcgi)

Tags: c++, windows, libraries, fastcgi

I am writing a simple service in c++. I have copied the example on
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus

verbatim, and everything works fine. Now I needed to add my code for the working thread. I add all of my files to the project, and at this point I still have the exact code from the link, so my project isn't really even using the other cpp/h files I just added. I try to start the service, and boom "cannot start in a timely fashion".

I have tried commenting out of the method definitions of the cpp files I have added, and I've figured out that any method that uses a function from the fastcgi libraries

(found here : http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/)

causes the service not to start. If I comment out every method uses the fastcgi library, the service will start (but I kind of need those).

Is there any way I can figure out why the use of these libraries are causing the windows service I'm making not to start? (everything works fine as a console application)

Thanks

Comment: The most likely cause is something bad happening in a DllMain function or in the constructor of a static object, presumably in the fastcgi library.  Can you modify the library code and narrow down on the exact problem by process of elimination, just as you did with the main code?

Comment: is there any sort of service start log or something I can do in visual studio that'll should be a stack trace ( or something else useful) on when it starts, so I can see what dll's it's using at startup?

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the MS website) might be useful.